# Problems with firebase services

Tags: firebase

I can't create and delete project on firebase and add new database firestore , Is there problems with google servers or the problem I have it only ?

Comment: Hello zaiej. Can you please show us the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

A network outage started across many Google services around 11:50 am pacific time. Some services have been recovering since about 12:40 pm. Keep an eye out on the [Firebase status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/) for updates.

Comment: is it will take long time for working again ? Note : I'm in the Middle East not in American

Comment: Oh It's working now thanks

Comment: Your own location is not the only thing that matters here. There's a good chance some of the services that you're using depend on other services that are hosted in one of the affected regions.